# Issues with { }

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-4

```
if (Request::ajax())
        {
            $orderItemData = Input::except('_method', '_token');

            if (array_key_exists('registered_no', $orderItemData))
            **{**
            $orderItemData['status'] = ($orderItemData['registered_no'] != '' ? 'arrived' : null);

            OrderItem::where('id', $orderItemId)->update($orderItemData);

            return Response::json(array('success' => 1, 'data' => $orderItemData));
            **}**

        }
```

This code works fine without the { } i bold above. Any idea why ? I'm trying to do a elseif but i cant because i cant put the { }  the code will fail(It doesn't response)

Comment: What happens if you leave them in? Do you get an error? Does the code return the wrong value?

Comment: How does the code fail?

Comment: Define fail? Is there an error message with it?

Comment: @CoreyOgburn It doesn't response if i put { }

Comment: It seems that `array_key_exists('registered_no', $orderedItemData)` is returning false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
if (condition)
    action
    anotherAction
```

will run `anotherAction` even if `condition` was false. But:

```
if (condition)
{
    action
    anotherAction
}
```

will not run either of the actions if `condition` was false. It is up to you which actions you want executed - include them in the `{ .. }` block and leave the rest out.

Comment: More specifically, his problem is that he doesn't return anything if the condition is not satisfied.

Comment: @Narf that's the interpreter's problem - _his_ problem is not understanding how the code is interpreted :/

Comment: I didn't disagree, and 'understanding' is indeed the key - I was trying to put it in an understandable way. :)